# Difference in log-rank, tarone-ware, gehan-breslow, Peto-Peto etc

Tags: survival, logrank-test

Everything is already in the title.

I study survival analisys

Could you tell me what is the difference among `log-rank, tarone-ware, gehan-breslow, Peto-Peto` etc....

In which case more suitable `log-rank` or `tarone-ware` etc
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Klein and Moeschberger's text "Survival Analysis" (p 195-197) has a nice comparison of these tests and a few others. They differ in the weighting of events along the course of the study: The Gehan test puts high weights on early deaths. Peto-Peto still weights early deaths higher but not quite so severely. Tarone-Ware is intermediate between the Gehan and Peto-Peto. The log-rank test has equal weighting. You can also construct various Fleming Harrington tests with higher weights at later times.